# css box-shadow not hidden on scroll

Tags: html, css

I put a box-shadow under a main content part. This works fine. However when scrolling, the main content is hidden behind the top parts (which have the same width as the main content parts) but the drop shadow is not. Is it somehow possible to show the shado only at thos parts where the element with the box-shadow is visible?
For illustration, [here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMcS3.png)

Comment: Can you provide your HTML please

Comment: And also your CSS. Add these as a snippet. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Even tho there is Code missing, I would suggest stretching the overlapping element over the window width. As the shadow is obviously not set to inset, and therefore rendered outside of the container boundaries.